# When I uninstall updates of system apps is it persistent?

Tags: applications, uninstallation, application-autoupdate

I don't want some apps updated (especially some of built-in apps). If I uninstall updates in settings is it for good or only to next phone restart? 
(I want to have auto updating in google play enabled)

Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable auto update from Google Play **Settings** section. To prevent auto update of a particular app, Go to that app page in play store & click the Options Menu on top right & uncheck "Auto-Update"

Answer (score 1):

yes uninstalls of updates is persistent, you can do it.

Comment: Even when new updates will be released?

Comment: update will be done either user manually updates or app gets auto updated. you can stop auto update in play store.